# How do I place the following queries to the Google Mail API

Tags: rest, google-api, gmail-api, postman, jsonresponse

I executed few requests through POSTMAN but I am always getting this error:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 404, 
    "message": "Not Found", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Not Found", 
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
   }
 }
```

these are the requests I have sent through the POSTMAN. Please advice how i can run these.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/{id}
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/history
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/labels/{id}
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/import
```

Comment: This is not enough information for us to go on. For starters, we'd need to see your actual code.